# Android after adding viewBinding true app can't build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, android-viewbinding

I've fully working application, then I've decided to migrate to viewBinding and it does not build anymore.

Here is my error -
[image: It seems like it's generating wrong binding classes, not sure, please help]
[image]

My gradle setup -
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `toggle_style.xml` file in your `layout` directory? Please include that file here (not as a screenshot, copy/paste the contents).

Comment: yes! I've moved it out of layout folder and everything worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a `toggle_style.xml` file in your `layout` directory that isn't actually a layout. You'll want to move that to the correct directory so that View Binding doesn't try to process that file.